# Looping same field in the same form (display as list) then all of the results get pushed into an array when submitted - mongodb, express, ejs, node js

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, ejs, push

I am really stuck with getting the issue resolved. I am very new to coding and hasn't been able to find any solution online.

These are the fields that I wish to be an array. I have created multiple inputs such as PIC#2 etc.

I am linking this model to another model schema so I would like that when I have selected the company, their corresponding PICs will be in another dropdown list. At the moment, it is showing all PIC1 which includes other companies' staffs. Please help out if you can make the coding simpler! Thank you in advance!

**html**

```
<div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="pic"><b>Person In Charge (PIC) #1</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="text" id="pic" name="company[pic]" required>
        </div>    
  
        <div class="row">         
        <div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="mobile"><b>Mobile</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="text" id="mobile" name="company[mobile]" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="email" id="email" name="company[email]"  required>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**model schema**

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
    name:  [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    code: String,
    pic: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    mobile: String,
    email: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    pic1: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic2: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic3: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic4: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic5: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic6: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic7: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic8: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic9: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    pic10: [{
        type: String,
        uppercase: true,
    }],
    mobile1: String,
    mobile2: String,
    mobile3: String,
    mobile4: String,
    mobile5: String,
    mobile6: String,
    mobile7: String,
    mobile8: String,
    mobile9: String,
    mobile10: String,
    email1: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email2: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email3: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email4: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email5: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }], 
    email6: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email7: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email8: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email9: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],
    email10: [{
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
    }],  
    remarks: String,
    status: String,
    upload: String,
    companyimage: String
});
```

**route**

```
app.get("/companies/new",  (req,res) => {
    res.render("companies/new")
});

app.post("/companies",async(req,res) => {
    // res.send(req.body)
    const company = new Company(req.body.company);
    await company.save();
    res.redirect(`/companies/${company._id}`)
});
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation of what you're trying to achieve, or post a bit more code for us to be able to help? Maybe it's just me, but I can't seem to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a form to add companies' information and inside there are their staff's name, mobile and email. Instead of adding one staff's details once at a time and saving them as separate objects, I wish to be able to add them in the one go in the same form which will create an array (e.g. id:1, company name: xxx, pic:[ x,y,z], mobile: [x,y,z], email, [x,y,z]). Sorry if I didn't explain it well but please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: I have two more questions before answering your question: what framework are you using in the front-end? and is your form consisting in a `<div>` for each PIC or just a reusable `<div>` for all PICs?

Comment: Hi Gaëtan, I think I am using node js as front-end framework. At the moment, the form is using a  ```div ``` for each PIC but would be great if I can reuse a ```div ``` so it is simpler to review and refer to in the future (i tried looping but it doesn't work). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have much context on what you're trying to achieve, I'll go through all I can think of to best answer this thread

### | NodeJS is not a front-end framework

NodeJS is a JavaScript runtime environment, which roughly means it reads and executes JS code you're giving it. A front-end framework is a set of tools and method that greatly helps you to code faster. It generally gives you higher level components so that you don't have to deal with low-level JS code yourself. Some examples are ReactJS, VueJS, Angular, etc...

I strongly advise you to take a look at these if you're going to build a web-app.

### | You might want to rework your database model

I won't tell you to rework your entire base code because that can be tiring and that's not the point of the question.

I'd put all PICs in a single array instead of having 10 fields, same thing goes for emails and mobiles. We can chat about it later on if you want to.

### | Answering the question

Given that I don't have much context about the stack used regarding the front-end, I sticked to plain JS and HTML. Here's **one method** (among many others):

index.js (to put front-end side)

```
//initializing the company object
const addedData = {
  id: 1,
  company: 'companyname',
  pic: [],
  mobile: [],
  email: []
}
//getting the buttons elements
const addPIC = document.getElementById('addpic');
const form = document.getElementById('sendform');

//listening on click event on the form
form.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // do what you have to here, e.g sending form
  const res = fetch("http://localhost:3000/companies", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(picArray)
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

// listening on click event when adding data
addPIC.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //getting input tags
 const pic = document.getElementById('pic');
  const mobile = document.getElementById('mobile');
  const email = document.getElementById('email');
  //pushing into respective arrays
  addedData.pic.push(pic.value);
  addedData.mobile.push(mobile.value);
  addedData.email.push(email.value);
  //resetting values to ease the process of mass adding PICs
  pic.value = '';
  mobile.value = '';
  email.value = '';
  //console.log(addedData);
});
```

and your html file (took your original file and just added 2 buttons, that's why it's not formatted properly):

```
<div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="pic"><b>Person In Charge (PIC) #1</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="text" id="pic" name="company[pic]" required>
        </div>    
  
        <div class="row">         
        <div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="mobile"><b>Mobile</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="text" id="mobile" name="company[mobile]" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 col">
            <label class="form-label" for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input class="form-control"type="email" id="email" name="company[email]"  required>
        </div>
        </div>
<button id="addpic">Add PIC</button>
<button id="sendform">Send form</button>
</div>
```

Now your back-end will receive the datas, but you'll have to process it once again to match your database model, which is not optimal.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sure will look into a front-end framework to help me out. I am getting  ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Company validation failed: mobile: Cast to string failed for value "[ '123456789', '' ]" at path "mobile" 
```  but I think I will take your advice and go through some courses before I proceed further with my web app. Thanks again and greatly appreciated for your time!

Comment: This error would be because you give an **array of values** when Mongoose is waiting for a **string** (hence the "you'll have to process it once again" in my original response).
No worries, glad I could help!